# How do I have a border-bottom on all except the last item

Tags: css, css-selectors

If i have a `ul`, how do i set a border-bottom on all the `li` items except the last one? I'm also trying to make the width of the `border` 180px. here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sideNav">
  <li><a href="/history.asp">History</a></li>
  <li><a href="/mission.asp">Mission</a></li>
  <li><a href="/associations.asp">Associations</a></li>
  <li><a href="/careers.asp">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.sideNav {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    width:216px;
    background-color:#017dc6;
}

.sideNav li {
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    width:180px;
}

.sideNav li a {
    border-bottom:1px solid #80bee3;
    width:180px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    padding:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Dec 13th, 2018: Note that there is no need to use this solution in today's modern browsers. You should feel free using the answer below mine `li:not(:last-child) { border-bottom: 1px solid red; }`

Without using JavaScript and not having to support IE7 and below (IE8 fails on the second one) there are three options you can use: `:first-child`, `:lastchild` and the `+` selector:

### :first-child

```
li { border-top: 1px solid red; }
li:first-child { border-top: none; }
```

### :last-child

```
li { border-bottom: 1px solid red; }
li:last-child { border-bottom: none; }
```

### + selector

```
li+li { border-top: 1px solid red; }
```

The problems arise if you need to support IE8 and your design doesn't allow you to put a border on the top of your elements as opposed to the bottom.

**EDIT:**
The fix to your width issue is that you're adding 180px to 2*18px of the `a` element, remove the left right padding, and set `padding: 18px 0;` and you'll be golden. (updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NLLqB/1/)

Here's a jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/NLLqB/

Comment: awesome! I definitely don't know what's going on in the li+li portion. And i kinda lost you at the padding 18 part. i read it like 4 times and don't get it... think you can expand on that one?

Comment: First - the LIs: li+li is any <li> that follows another <li>, so in the your example that would be Mission, Associations and Careers.

Comment: Padding: Padding is added to four sides and can be written explicitly (padding-top, padding-bottom, etc.) or in shorthand (padding). Most people start out writing shorthand (ex: padding: 18px) as a single value which adds the padding to all 4 sides at once, but you can also write in shorthand giving each side different values. Here are the shorthands: 18px 18px 18px 0 (top, right and bottom=18px, left=0. 18px 0 (top and bottom 18px, right and left 0). 18px 0 0 (top 18px, right and left=0 and bottom=0).

Comment: @JoSo - you're being pedantic - css is aesthetic. There is nothing at all wrong with utilizing any of these options, and considering that the optimal one, :last-child isn't supported in IE8 (along with :not) I feel that the first-child and the element selector win out for css solutions. If you only ever give the answer to the question and not the answer to the need, you're not going to get very far in life.

Comment: Part two on padding: The default width of an element is width + padding + border (search for the box model if you want more details), so if you have width: 180px; and padding:18px; the overall width of your border will be 216px. Setting margin: 0 auto; and padding: 18px 0; allows your container to be 180px and sit in the middle of your UL.

Comment: Check  the answer down below, that's the best option.

Answer (score 36):

Use `:not(:last-child)`.

```
.sideNav li:not(:last-child) a {
    /* your css here */
}
```

Comment: Just try it out. It does (Iceweasel 17.0.8 here)

Comment: 1+ This definitely works, and it doesn't require you to overwrite pre-existing properties.. http://jsfiddle.net/MAcZa/

Comment: @JoshC not really you dont have any other elements in your example fiddle check out this one.. http://jsfiddle.net/FTz45/ It will affect all the last child in an html plus it is always only reliable to use simple selectors with not. Check the fiddle in my comment and the one in my answer. you will see the difference.

Comment: @PSL Not unless you apply it correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/efFeh/ see, it works. It produces the same results as yours, yet it doesn't required you to overwrite any existing CSS.

Comment: @JoshC haha whats the difference with my example you still have 2 rules... Try with the one in this answer.

Comment: @JoshC No seriously combining it with not in a multilevel selector is always tricky i believe...

Comment: @PSL Nonetheless, both solutions work perfectly fine.

Comment: @JoshC My initial comment was based on the rule provided in the answer.. :) it seems like he is trying to apply it with one selector... If you split into 2 definitely its gonna work fine.. But i dont know how to apply it probably...

Comment: @PSL: It's not counting rules in an arbitrary representing instance. It's about the ugly and wrong resetting or avoiding it.

Comment: @JoSo If this works... Then your statement is valid. Baseline is a solution should work right.. I am not trying to pull you down, did you check the fiddle in my comment applying your solution.

Comment: @JoSo Now you downvoted my answer for what? As i said i am not trying to criticize the answer, if you can prepare a fiddle for OP sample with the example you posted as as he expects i will vote you up...

Comment: @JoSo BTW it is easy to find out who downvoted the answer... :) Also let me know when you change your mind to un downvote mine (I will edit then you can reverse). I could have easily downvoted yours without commenting.. But i commented giving you a chance to fix your answer.

Comment: @PSL: Why should I prepare yet another fiddle? There are already at least two out there. I have verified that my solution works. You can verify easily by modifying one of the existing fiddles. And, downvoting a (in one's opinion) inferior or even wrong answer is not a crime.

Comment: @PSL: And yes, I have checked your fiddle and it says nothing about why `:not` should not work just like it's supposed to do. Your argument can be reduced to "Your solution doesn't work if not applied correctly". It's completely void. It seems you haven't got the point about avoiding css resets (which aren't cleanly possible) and selecting the right sets from the start.

Comment: @joso there are no fiddles out here that makes ur solution work. Why you think op did not choose your answer. Just compare the result of ur ex with the fiddle in other 2 answers. Downvote  was becaus3 it just doesnt work in any means. Lol

Answer (score 3):

One way: You can override for the last one using a rule like below with **[:last-child](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child)** (Since you tagged css3):

```
.sideNav li:last-child a {
    border-bottom:0px; /*Reset the border for the anchor of last li of this ul*/
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M37qD/)**

There are polyfills available for IE8, but if you can provide a classname for the last one and apply rule to it to reset the style would be of better support, rather than using css3 (if your intention is to support older browsers as well).

if you are using scripting language like jquery you can easily add a class to the last child as jquery takes care of cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: -1 Sorry for not commenting my downvote below this post. But I had already explained why I consider this one an unclean solution in a comment below my own post. So I'm not really getting why you're so annoyed about a single downvote.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use in-line CSS to correct this problem.

```
<li><a style="border-bottom:none" href="/careers.asp">Careers</a></li>
```

This will remove the border from the "Careers" link.  Note that it will only work if you put that code in the `<a>` tag since that is what the border is being applied to, not the `<li>`.

The downside of this is that if you add something to the list, then the second-to-last list item will have no bottom border, and the last *will.*

Not the best solution, but an alternative one that accomplishes the same thing.  Cheers!