# Dynamically add border on div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In a series of divs containing tables that can be clicked and removed I removed the bottom border to prevent a 'doubled up' border look.  However, now I am stumped as to how to add a bottom border but only on whatever element is last/on the bottom.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/phamousphil/t82qsd69/

Javascript code below that handles the disappearing act for the divs.  Could I augment that function to help here?

```
$(function () {
    var nContainer = $(".notification-popup-container");

    $("a.notification-popup-delete").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(nContainer).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329459/how-do-i-have-a-border-bottom-on-all-except-the-last-item

Comment: @mkaatman :last-child (as answered below) works.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `:last-child` css selector.

```
.notification-popup-container:last-child {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t82qsd69/3/

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

Comment: That assumes that `.notification-popup-container` is the last element in its parent, as opposed to just the last container in it.

Comment: Correct, but from the code one would assume that `.notification-popup-container-main` will only contain `.notification-popup-container` elements.

Comment: What if my `.notification-popup-container` class has two variations?  In my non-fiddle code doing something like `.notification-popup-container.other:last-child` for each variant (in this case it is border color) does not return expected results.

Comment: Based on OP code it contain only `<div>` elements. If there are other types [:last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) could be used. @phamousphil please add an example.

Comment: I was able to get this working with a tweak to my code.  :last-child works, even with the variants as I mentioned above. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/phamousphil/t82qsd69/5/

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your CSS you can add an extra rule that applies to the last item.

`.notification-popup-container-main .notification-popup-container:last-child { border-bottom: 1px solid #75C3E0; }`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t82qsd69/4/

Answer (score 0):

if i understood what you mean, just add `$('.notification-popup-container:last-child').css('border-bottom', '1px solid red');` inside the click function (below `$(this).closest(nContainer).remove();`) so when you delete a div, this script check if the last element has the border bottom (it it already has a border the sript will ignore this css rule)